# Which Event do I have to use when copying Text from one Textfield to an other in Acrobat Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, events, adobe, acrobat

Which event do I have to use to copy Text from one Textfield in Adobe Acrobat into an other? I want the Text to be copied when I click outside of the textfield. is this possible or is there another way i should use?

The code i Tried is the following:

the text need to be copied from ks0 to ks1 and auft1 should show 100%.

```
var ks0 = getField("ks0");
var ks1 = getField("ks1");
var auft1 = getField("auft1");
if(event.change === ks0)
    {
    getField("ks1").value = getField("ks0").valueAsString;
    getField("auft1").value = "100%";
    }
```

Comment: And what happens with your code? Errors? Nothing?

Comment: nothing happens. is the way i chose even the right one?

Comment: I have not used AcrobatJS for the last 15 years, but I suspect `event.change === ks0` can you remove that and see if the other field gets a value? I mean just have `getField("ks1").value = getField("ks0").valueAsString;
    getField("auft1").value = "100%";` without the test

Answer (score 0):

Use the "ks0" field On Blur" event. The code below should work.

```
this.getField("ks1").value = event.target.value;
this.getField("auft1").value = "100%";
```

Comment: do I have to use the onblur event in my if statement like this?: if((event.onblur === ks0)

Comment: No - "On Blue" is a selection for the field actions. Only that field will trigger that event.